# Bash script failing of no reason

Tags: bash, cloud-foundry

I have this bash script (actually a part of https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi/blob/master/bin/compile with echo I've added myself):

```
echo "[DEBUG] chmod done"

framework=$($dir/bin/detect $1)

echo "[DEBUG] $framework done"
```

And I see in the log:

```
[DEBUG] chmod done
Staging failed: Buildpack compilation step failed
```

And I do not see the second echo in the logs at all.
I do not know much bash unfortunately. Could anybody explain to me in what case the first echo performs and second do not? I always thought that both echo should always work no matter whether the second line succeeds or not.

Comment: @shellter Thanks. It's just a matter of debugging. I will remove echo once I find out what's not working in the setup I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not visible in your question, but clicking on your link, it says in the third line

```
set -e
```

This means to stop processing the script immediately whenever an error occurs. Comment that line, and the script should run through and also print the second `echo` statement.

Note that I didn't inspect what the script actually does and I cannot tell you if commenting out `set -e` is actually good advice or not.

From `man set`:

> −e:    When this option is on, when any command fails (for any of the  reasons  listed
>         in  Section  2.8.1, Consequences of Shell Errors or by returning an exit status
>         greater than zero), the shell immediately shall exit with the following  excep‐
>         tions:
>
> ```
>    1. The failure of any individual command in a multi-command pipeline shall not
>       cause the shell to exit. Only the failure of the pipeline itself  shall  be
>       considered.
>
>    2. The  −e setting shall be ignored when executing the compound list following
>       the while, until, if, or elif reserved word, a pipeline beginning with  the
>       !  reserved word, or any command of an AND-OR list other than the last.
>
>    3. If  the exit status of a compound command other than a subshell command was
>       the result of a failure while −e was being ignored, then −e shall not apply
>       to this command.
>
>   This requirement applies to the shell environment and each subshell environment
>   separately. For example, in:
>
>       set -e; (false; echo one) | cat; echo two
>
>   the false command causes the subshell to exit without executing echo one;  how‐
>   ever, echo two is executed because the exit status of the pipeline (false; echo
>   one) | cat is zero.
> ```